# MySQL not null timestamp returning null

Tags: mysql, jdbc, clojure

I have code querying a MySQL 5.5.47 database on a remote server. I'm having an intermittent issue with a created timestamp field that sometimes is being returned as null. I'm wondering if it's possible that there is a transaction issue and that the timestamp field is not being written right away. Behavior is as follows:

- Write to DB
- Use generated id key to access the item that was just written
- Seemingly at random the created field is returned null

I'm thinking it's pretty unlikely, but is there a chance that the creation and writing of the created field is done in a separate transaction and the query to read the item is completed before the created field is committed? Using clojure using yesql, here is the code I have:

```
(let [foo (:foo input)
  errors (Validator foo)]
  (if (empty? errors)
     (let [foo (-> (db/with-connection insert-foo<! foo)
                      :generated_key
                      (find-by-id user-id))]
        (index-foo user-id foo (search/connect))
        [true nil])
     [false errors]))
```

and here is create table for the table:

```
foo | CREATE TABLE `foo` (
      `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      ......
      `created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
      ......
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=272 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
```

Comment: You should be more specific, especially, how do you retrieve the Id of newly added row?

Comment: To answer your question there are some itens you need to answer: 1- does the creation operation include the timestamp field? 2 - the timestamp field allows null values? 3 - how are you retrieving the generated id key? And for: "is there a chance that the creation and writing of the created field is done in a separate transaction" it depends on how you are saving it.

Comment: The creation operation is not included in the timestamp field. It is generated by the DB as a Not Null timestamp field with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP default value.
I am retrieving the generated ID using the JDBC driver. It is being returned after the initiation write. Sorry, I should have included that in the initial question.

Comment: Add the results of show create table to this post.
Also verify from the console if the row in question is set to 0000:00:00 00:00:00.
Not sure about jdbc, but python's MySQLdb interprets that as NULL so there is some precedent for other drivers handling it that way.
Some versions of the mysql console will also accept queries on timestamps/datetimes with a value of NULL and interpret it as that.  It may throw some warnings though.

Comment: `created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
Nothing is showing up as 0000:00:00 00:00:00. When I query the DB on my own after, everything is showing as it should. It's just when run I code that it is returning things inconsistently.

Comment: You need to **edit** your question with the details, and provide an [mcve]